How does Powershell know which property to Print out by Default
I have a text file @ C:\Sandpit\File.txt with contents as follows
This
is
a
multi
line
file

If I run a Select-String in Powershell, I get a single match:
$result = Get-Content C:\Sandpit\File.txt | Select-String -Pattern "file"
and I can see the type of $result
$result.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    MatchInfo                                System.Object

and its members:
$result | Get-Member


   TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo

Name         MemberType Definition
----         ---------- ----------
Equals       Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode  Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType      Method     type GetType()
RelativePath Method     string RelativePath(string directory)
ToString     Method     string ToString(), string ToString(string directory)
Context      Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfoContext Context {get;set;}
Filename     Property   string Filename {get;}
IgnoreCase   Property   bool IgnoreCase {get;set;}
Line         Property   string Line {get;set;}
LineNumber   Property   int LineNumber {get;set;}
Matches      Property   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[] Matches {get;set;}
Path         Property   string Path {get;set;}
Pattern      Property   string Pattern {get;set;}

If I print out the object, I get the the text of the match.
Write-Output $result

file

This appears to be printing the Line property of the $result object:
Write-Output $result.Line
file

and the string representation of the object returns the same
Write-Output $result.ToString()
file

My question is, when I do Write-Output $result is this doing Write-Output $Result.ToString() behind the scenes or is there something about the property line in the class Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo that is marking it as "default" or similar?

If there are no visual properties, PowerShell uses the .ToString() method to display a class instance to the user unless (as in this example class) it is defined in the Format.ps1xml file where it is overruled by the PowerShell source code.
Excerpt from about_Format.ps1xml:

Beginning in PowerShell 6, the default views are defined in PowerShell
source code. The Format.ps1xml files from PowerShell 5.1 and earlier
versions don't exist in PowerShell 6 and later versions.
The PowerShell source code defines the default display of objects in
the PowerShell console. You can create your own Format.ps1xml files to
change the display of objects or to define default displays for new
object types that you create in PowerShell.
When PowerShell displays an object, it uses the data in structured
formatting files to determine the default display of the object. The
data in the formatting files determines whether the object is rendered
in a table or in a list, and it determines which properties are
displayed by default.
The formatting affects the display only. It doesn't affect which
object properties are passed down the pipeline or how they're passed.
Format.ps1xml files can't be used to customize the output format for
hash tables.

You can retrieve this format data with the Get-FormatData cmdlet:
$Result = 'file' | Select-String -Pattern 'file'
$Result.GetType().FullName
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo

$FormatData = Get-FormatData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo
$FormatData

TypeNames                                 FormatViewDefinition
---------                                 --------------------
{Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo} {MatchInfo}

Somewhere deep down the ExtendedTypeDefinition class, you will find the actual command expression that is used to define the default view:
$FormatData.FormatViewDefinition.Control.Entries.CustomItems.Expression.Value

Which returns:
$_.ToEmphasizedString(((get-location).path))

This expression is used to display the concerned class instance to the user:
$Result.ToEmphasizedString(((get-location).path)) -Replace [Char]27,'<esc>'
<esc>[7mfile<esc>[0m

To create a specific display view for a custom object class, see the helpful answer from mklement0: stackoverflow.com/a/77753690/1701026
